# Im a beginner on react. I want to save all the values in each LI, and some general guidelines on how i should use the props

Tags: reactjs

Code on the link below (you'll need to click on the "x" when you see "unexpected error"

https://codesandbox.io/s/9lj4mmon1o

On the todo list im trying to get the task name, the select menu value and ticket number value to be listed in the "completed" state. Im trying to call these for the"list.js" but it's not reading the ticketID. Could someone please take a look and give me some guidance. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In `Form.js` you have a div with an invalid property `class`, you have to use the property `className`.

This is your code:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Form= props=> {

return (

        <form onSubmit={props.submit}>
            <div className="input-group col-lg-6 mx-auto">
                <input type='text' className='form-control' value={props.myValue} onChange={props.eventHandler}/>
                    <div class="input-group-append"> <!-- HERE "class" should be className -->
                        <button className='btn btn-outline-secondary'> Submit</button>

                    </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    )

}
```

You have to change: 
    
to:

I hope it helps you. Bye.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i realise there are a few errors in there! Im just really struggling with the passing terms part, do you have any idea how i could call the values from the li and place it into another state object?